# Photoshop changing colors when saving JPG

Tags: jpeg, photoshop

I'm in photoshop and I have an image with the color #293344 and when I go to save a JPG the color changes to 2a3344. I've attachedthe export settings.  I have tried to embed, not embed, convert to RGB and not, etc. and keep getting the same outcome.

[Here are the export settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgVOQ.png)

Comment: For non-coding questions please see other stack exchange sites: like Graphic Design stack exchange for instance (https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 0):

I talked to a friend and did "save as" vs. export as a JPG and that kept the colors. No idea what's up with the export when I saved the pallet but hopefully this helps someone else.